# Conversations in Mail not in chronological order

Tags: mail.app, email

some conversations in my Mail are not shown in chronological order. The dates seem completely ordered at random. I have "Show most recent message at the top" enabled. But it shows no order at all, here an example:

1. a sent mail from 17.12.2018
2. a received mail from 14.12.2018
3. a sent mail from 21.12.2018
4. a received mail from 20.12.2018

Unchecking "Show most recent message at the top" just reverses the order.

I tried Mailbox -> Rebuild. It does not do anything.

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: There is a sort feature that overrides the recent messages on top. It can be seen in the same column as the message list and sits on the top left corner of the column. On the right is the unread(default) filter.